# clear html webpage?

Tags: php, html

i am currently developing a crawler that crawls all links on the web and displays them in the web browser (and saving it of course).

but after some hours there will be a huge list displayed on the web browser and i want to only display lets say 1000 links at the same time. then i clear the html and display another 1000 links. this is also good for the RAM or it will eat up all memory.

how do i clear the web browser screen?

EDIT: i have seen some scripts using some flush buffer functions. has this anything to do with my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `document.write('')` to completely delete the contents of the web page without reloading it.

Comment: I would test whether this actually clears the page from the browser's memory. It could be that it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

[Pagination: What is it and how to do it?](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/pagination.html) Sounds like you're describing a perfect opportunity to paginate your results.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear the screen in a way that saves memory on the client's side, you'll have no choice but to do redirect to a different page, e.g. using JavaScript: `location.href="..."`. That will trigger the loading of a completely new page though, so you would have to save your crawler's state and continue from the saved point.